# Sending And Receiving Data Via Game Center (GameKit) Over 3G Stops Working

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit

I have a Game Center matchmaker working and implemented, and by using Game Kit's Bluetooth functionality I know that my multiplayer code works. When playing over the internet through the Game Center sandbox, it works when both devices are on WiFi, but if one is on 3G it quickly stops sending and receiving data, and so the game grinds to a halt. Does anyone have an idea why on earth this is happening?

EDIT:
After further debugging, the problem is that data is just not received on the 3G device after a certain point. Any ideas?

EDIT2:
I have created a simple test program that fails around 6,000 for me. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2042276/Game%20Center%203G%20Test.zip (change the bundle ID)

Comment: do you get any error's in completion blocks ?

Comment: It doesn't use completion blocks. The method seems to still return `YES`, and the `NSError` passed in remains `nil`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem - although my packets were incredibly small, I was sending lots of them. I fixed it by lumping packets together and sending them as one big packet.

Answer (score 1):

Silly idea probably, but have you tried rebooting your iDevice and resetting your network settings.

Comment: I've rebooted, but not reset network settings. It was a new device when I tested it, so I'm not sure it would make a difference.